# <s:token/> warning message struts2

Tags: struts2, token, csrf

When using

```
<s:token/>
```

with ***Struts 2*** I got this warning message in the log

```
WARN [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack] - <Error setting expression
'struts.token.name' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@7023f'>
```

How can I avoid that?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have multiple <s:token/> in your form.

> [Ljava.lang.String

indicates that a String array is send, that happens if your form sends the same field multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I found that cannot avoid WARN's but we can setup a filter with Log4J,

check this...

https://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/troubleshooting-guide-migrating-from-struts-20x-to-21x.html#TroubleshootingguidemigratingfromStruts2.0.xto2.1.x-MissingProperties

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case, the following was missing in struts.xml:

```
<interceptor-ref name="token"/>
```

Inside my action.